# Connection refused in Suds but not a browser

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm using [Suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) 0.4 and can't connect to it from there, but I *can* see it in a browser. Here's what I'm doing:

```
from suds.client import Client
Client('http://10.1.0.123:7090/Endpoint?wsdl')
```

This creates a nasty stack trace which culminates in error 61:

> urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>

On Windows, the error is slightly different wording but is the same:

> urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

Oddly, when I open the above URL in a browser, it works fine! I can also cURL it. I can even use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and see the file, leading me to believe the error is somewhere in Suds.

Also, I get 404 errors when I connect to different URLs; I don't get the same connection refused error.

If it helps, I'm on OS X Python 2.7.7 and have the same issue on a Windows Python 2.7.6.